# Django - add a link with custom admin page - need direct href to Admin Panel

Tags: django, href, admin

I have Django app called my_app with 12 models: ModelA, ModelB, ModelC,...etc. In front end I have views with tables and from those tables I would like to open admin panel (by clicking proper button or link) with corresponging model type and object with corresponding id for edit purpose or delete purpose. How the custom link in frontend should look like?

When - for example - model is ModelD and id = 9 than my link to admin panel (from browser) look like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/my_app/modeld/9/change/
```

How should I redirect an user from front end to admin panel in this case? I have seen sth like:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:**.....???**' %}" class="btn btn-high btn-success">Edit modelD with ID equal to 9</a>
```

What should I use here?

Comment: I would suggest reading the [documentation on reversing admin URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls) which is quite detailed and has the answers you seek with examples.

Comment: Finding interesting topics in docs is another skill I should master - thanks!